# Creating a view with sums from multiple tables (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sum

I'm trying to create a view that gets the sums of a couple of different rows in various tables. (I'm not sure how to explain this properly)

Here is how my tables are set out:

Visitors:

```
VISITORID FNAME           LNAME           PHONE              HOTELID
---------- --------------- --------------- --------------- ----------
        23 Bella           Morgan          0394110625               3
```

Bookings:

```
BOOKINGID    HOTELID     ROOMNO BOOKINGDATE         BOOKINGDAYS BEDANDBREA  VISITORID
---------- ---------- ---------- ------------------- ----------- ---------- ----------
        28          3        509 28-04-2013 00:00:00           3 Yes                23
```

Rooms:

```
    ROOMNO    HOTELID ROOMTYPE                  PRICE
---------- ---------- ------------------------- ----------
       509          3 Double                    700
```

Services:

```
SERVICEID  SERVICENAME                                        COST          HOTELID
---------- -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
1-CLTH     Cloth Cleaning                                     14.95               1
2-RMSV     Room Service                                       9.95                2
```

Booking_services:

```
SERVICEID   BOOKINGID
---------- ----------
2-RMSV             32
1-CLTH             32
```

I want to create a view called bills that gives me the total of room cost and cost of all services.

To get the room price, the sum is rooms.price*bookings.bookingdays.
For the services, it's the sum of all the rows in the services table that match the SERVICEID in booking_services for the matching bookingID.

Currently there are more rows in all of the tables than I've shown (so it doesn't take up too much space on here) and I have a query but it's only showing 2 of the visitors that i'd like the total for. I know it's because of line 5, but I'm not sure how I can get it to calculate that as well as those who do not have a row in booking_services.

Here is that query:

```
CREATE VIEW bills AS
SELECT v.fname, SUM((r.price*b.bookingdays)+s.cost) AS total
FROM visitors v, rooms r, bookings b, services s, booking_services bs
WHERE v.visitorid = b.visitorid
AND
s.serviceid in(select bs.serviceid from booking_services where bs.bookingid = b.bookingid)
AND
b.roomno = r.roomno
GROUP BY v.fname;
```

Any help to get what I'm after (if this makes any sense) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Here is the SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c1dad/12)**

**You can try below query for your view:**

```
Select v.fname, sum((r.price*b.bookingdays)+nvl(bso.cost,0))
  From visitors v 
  Join bookings b
    on v.visitorid = b.visitorid
  Join rooms r
    on b.roomno = r.roomno
  left outer join (select bs.BOOKINGID,sum(cost) as cost 
                     from booking_services bs
                     Join services s
                       on s.SERVICEID = bs.SERVICEID
                    group by bs.BOOKINGID) bso
    on bso.BOOKINGID = b.BOOKINGID

GROUP BY v.fname;
```